# error: no > match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr, ros

I have rather a basic knowledge in c++ and there is an issue described in the following which is likely rather simple and a based on a syntax mistake but I haven't figured out a way around it. 
Basically the error I get says:

```
remote_hw_interface_node.cpp:23:68:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:231:11: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, ROBOTHardwareInterface, const boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::JointState_<std::allocator<void>
> > >&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::JointState_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
            BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(boost::mem_fn(*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));

    ^
```

which I don't have any clue what it is about regarding boost.

regarding my code I have copied some parts of it in the following which may likely show the problem for a more experienced c++ user. My header file looks like:

```
#pragma once

#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_sequencer.h>


// controller manager and interface msgs
#include <controller_manager/controller_manager.h>


class ROBOTHardwareInterface : public hardware_interface::RobotHW 
{
    public:
        ROBOTHardwareInterface(ros::NodeHandle& nh);
        ~ROBOTHardwareInterface();

        bool init                 (const urdf::Model* const urdf_model);
        void sequential_update    (const boost::shared_ptr <sensor_msgs::JointState> & joint_state_msg);


    // main
        ros::NodeHandle nh_;
        ros::Duration elapsed_time_;
        boost::shared_ptr<controller_manager::ControllerManager> controller_manager_;
};
```

the cpp file also if I only copy the relevant parts which has also caused the error coming up:

```
#include <remote_hw.h>

ROBOTHardwareInterface::ROBOTHardwareInterface(ros::NodeHandle& nh) : nh_(nh) {

    message_filters::Subscriber <sensor_msgs::JointState> sub(nh_, "joint_cmd_topic", 1);
    message_filters::TimeSequencer <sensor_msgs::JointState> seq(sub, ros::Duration(
    0.1), ros::Duration(0.01), 10);
    seq.registerCallback(&ROBOTHardwareInterface::sequential_update);

}

ROBOTHardwareInterface::~ROBOTHardwareInterface() {
}}

void ROBOTHardwareInterface::sequential_update(const boost::shared_ptr <sensor_msgs::JointState> & joint_state_msg){
```

Answer (score 0):

By searching in boost library implementation https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp, it seems that you are trying to call a method without giving all the parameters necessary.

I suppose that you try to invoke this method with an empty parameter, while you should also add `const boost::shared_ptr <sensor_msgs::JointState> &` as well.

I suppose that BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS in your case is empty hence your issue. So the method behind is trying to invoke `void sequential_update()` instead of `void sequential_update(const boost::shared_ptr <sensor_msgs::JointState> &)`

I hope this helps.

Comment: but where should I add "const boost::shared_ptr <sensor_msgs::JointState> &" exactly, the sequential_update update already has it as an argument right?

Comment: Yes but I think the error comes from how you register the callback. You will need to check how ```message_filters::TimeSequencer``` is calling the callback you created. Maybe when you register the callback you need to add several parameters representing the arguments of the callback.

Comment: The error itself as far as I see it is on the call of this callback. The caller is the black box that you are using which is not using the callback properly giving it the joint_state_msg that you declared.

Comment: the examples I saw here: https://answers.ros.org/question/323115/message_filters-timesequencer-compile-error/ or https://answers.ros.org/question/283432/message-filters-time-sequencer-not-compiling-roscpp/, and the original, http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters,  simply use seq.registerCallback(myCallback); but sinceI am using it in a class, I add &.

Comment: This might be the issue: ```const boost::shared_ptr <const sensor_msgs::JointState> & joint_state_msg)``` Not having const in the declaration of ```boost::shared_ptr```

Comment: Based on their doc it seems that they expect the object to be const

Comment: changing them to "const boost::shared_ptr <const sensor_msgs::JointState> & joint_state_msg" didn't work either :/. there is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322075/ros-message-filterstimesequencer which I had mainly looked at and someone suggests boost::bind, but so far that hasn't worked either

Comment: Could you try message_filters::TimeSequencer <const boost::shared_ptr <sensor_msgs::JointState> & > and the method sequential_update to be the same as before ?

Comment: https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/message_filters/html/c++/time__sequencer__unittest_8cpp_source.html . You have here his example. It seems that you need to the a std::bind.
In your case it should be:

ROBOTHardwareInterface interface;
seq.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ROBOTHardwareInterface::sequential_update, &interface, _1));
You might need to move the registration outside of the class.Or to have something like:

**seq.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ROBOTHardwareInterface::sequential_update, this, _1));**

Comment: It might also work  seq.registerCallback(&ROBOTHardwareInterface::sequential_update, this);

Comment: @afkid adding a parameter this where it is not expected? That does not work